# PHP and SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL database with table for storing inventory of video games. The following PHP code accesses that database and specific table and I would like to print only the video games that have 10 or in stock. The quantity for the video games is stored in my "inventory" table as "quantity" Thank you in advanced.

```
<?php

// Construct query
$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory";

// Perform the query, gather results
$results = mysql_query( $query )
    or die ( "Sorry, could not get the data ". mysql_error() );

echo "<div style=margin-bottom:10px;>Number of games found with quantity > 10 is ". "</div>\n";

// Create loop to print all found records
// That are contained inside of the $results variable
for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($results); $i++ ) {

    if ( $gamearray['quantity'] > 10) {

        $gamearray = mysql_fetch_array( $results );
        echo "<div>Title of game is ". $gamearray['title'] ."</div>\n";
        echo "<div>Quantity in stock is ". $gamearray['quantity'] ."</div>\n";
        echo "<div style=margin-bottom:10px;>With a critic score of ". $gamearray['metascore'] ." This game is</div>\n";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on `WHERE` clauses in SQL.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP dude but hope this helps to narrow down your issue.

Don't you have to fetch the contents to `$gamearray` first to check the quantity value? You seem to do it after, in the `if` container.

How are you iterating through the results ? 
Like how does `mysql_fetch_array` know that it should get data for row 1, row 2 row n-1..
Aren't you supposed to have something like this `mysql_fetch_array($results[i])`?

Be sure to use length - 1 here `for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($results) - 1; $i++ )` to avoid index out of bound. If its 0 based...

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE quantity > 10";
```

This should fetch all the entries where the quantity is more than 10. Also, you do not need the `if` statement now. 
You can structure and loop through the results like :

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo("Title:" . $row[0] . "Quantity :" . row[1]);  
   }
}
```

Where the numbers 0, 1 would refer to the order of the columns in `inventory` i.e the first column in the query is Title and second is Quantity and so on. This should get you started.